# How to create auth.uid for custom authentication firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am new to firebase and am creating messaging app and using private otp service for registering phone number.i am using both real-time database and firestore so I need to protect database in security rules.it seems like using auth.uid is the only way to use in security rules.

I am saving chat thread in real-time database and saving user profiles in firestore.

How can I create auth.uid for security rules for my users phonenumber thats authenticated using private otp service.

Please help me how can I approach this.

Comment: It seems that you should look at Firebase phone authentication: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth. Note that with the Admin SDK you can set the value of the user uid, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I don't want to use firebase phone auth. especially signinwithphonenumber sends new otp SMS with recaptcha(I don't like the ui flow)but I already verified phonenumber using private otp service.can I create auth.uid for my verified phonenumber from client.as per your suggestion ,is setting value of uid using admin sdk from client safe.is it safe approach.

Comment: "can I create auth.uid for my verified phonenumber from client.as per your suggestion ,is setting value of uid using admin sdk" => Yes. For that you need to use a backend server that you control, or easier a Cloud Function. "from client safe ... is it safe approach" => This is actually difficult to answer. It all depends on how clients (and which cleints, e.g. Admin?) call the Cloud Function from the front end.

Comment: You will probably be interested by this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-an-admin-module-for-managing-users-access-and-roles-34a94cf31a6e) which shows how to create an Admin module for managing Firebase users access and roles. We don't specify the user id when creating it in the Cloud Function but you just need to follow the example shown in the link above (my first comment) `admin.auth().createUser({uid: 'some-uid', phoneNumber: '+11234567890'})`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec so I need to set uid value using admin sdk from cloud function.i will look into it.thank you so much.if I ever face any struggle with creating uid .may I ask doubt again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Renaud commented, you'll want to:

1. Sign in the user into your own custom backend.
2. Use the information from this sign-in to [generate a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) with the Firebase Admin SDK
3. Pass the custom token to the client.
4. [Sign the user in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) to Firebase on the client with the custom token.

At this point the information from the custom token is available in the security rules for Firestore and Realtime Database.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer.i have one doubt.can you help me to understand how this custom token works.can hackers spoof the user info and create their own custom token to access database.

Comment: Generating a token requires the private credentials of your project. If those credentials fall in the hands of malicious users, they have full access to your project, so it's key to keep them only in a trusted environment.

Comment: After verifying phonenumber with private otp service. I am triggering cloud function with phonenumber as uid to create custom token to signin.what happens if malicious user use his friends phonenumber to trigger cloud function to get custom token by reverse engineering and sign-in to access his friends database.how it actually works.if it is the case how can I avoid this situation.

Comment: It sounds like step 1 of my answer isn't secured properly in your scenario. The Firebase documentation for phone number authentication contains a note about this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#security-concerns

Comment: It seems like there is no other way other than use of password with phone verification to protect database from unauthorized data access.

Comment: instead of password i tried to use time difference to protect unauthorized login but I face some difficulty with creating custom token. can you please help me rectify my code.i created as a new question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67143220/creating-custom-token-in-cloud-function-after-reteiving-data-from-realtime-datab].please look into this question.